# Trying to update a field in my DB using a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have been on this all day and after searching many websites (including this one) i came to the conclusion that my question hasn't been asked before probably due to my incompetence.

I have a prepared statement here that i would like to update my password field in my DB depending on the username and email, the reason it is updating and not inserting is because its part of my security to not approve site photographers until they have been sent a link

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['approved-photographer'])) {
    require 'dbh.php';

    $username  = $_POST['username'];
    $email     = $_POST['mail'];
    $password  = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password-repeat'];

    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || 
        empty($password2)) 
    {
        header("location:signup.php?error=emptyfields&username=" . $username 
    . "&mail=.$email");
        exit();
     } elseif ($password !== $password2) {
        header("location:approvedphoto.php?error=passwordcheck&username=" . 
        $username . "&mail=" . $email);
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT Password 
                FROM photographers 
                WHERE Username= '$username' 
                AND Email= '$email'";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("location:approvedphoto.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO photographers (Password) VALUES (?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("location:approvedphoto.php?error=sqlerror2");
            exit();
        } else {
            $hashedpwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $hashedpwd);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            header("location:signin.php?signup=success");
            exit();
        }
        }
        }
        }
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading

Comment: You dont set `$hashedpwd` before attempting to use it in the UPDATE. And lots more issues in this code as well

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: You don't actually bind your variables. Have a look at the manual, http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.prepare

Comment: Some proper formatting of the code could also help :-)

Comment: Ow right i see, im having such trouble with this, so bind my variables first. Thanks

Comment: Do you really have newlines in the middle of your `header()` parameters

Comment: When i try it this way with my variables bind, it creates a new row in the database with only  aPassword filled in

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your code, see how much easier that is to read? :-)

Comment: If you're seeing new rows, you're running a `INSERT` query, not an `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Qirel Ha I was doing that also, you beet me by seconds

Comment: UPDATE commands DO NOT Create New Rows

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: so by changing my INSERT to UPDATE this should fix the issue i will try this real quick

Comment: **WHAT INSERT** You only show us code with an UPDATE in it ??????????

Comment: RiggsFolly, Thanks I will add this in as well i appreciate all feedback, im fairly new to this and web dev is not my thing 3D is my area

Comment: **Code formatting** @Qirel You or me this time?

Comment: Sorry i thought i clicked update edit and it didnt:/ this is what i had when it was creating a new field instead up updating an old one. Thanks for being patient

Comment: when i leave INSERT INTO in the code is does as previously mentioned new field with only a password, when i change INSERT INTO to UPDATE my sqlerror2 gets kicked up

Comment: looks dangerous to put user controled data in a header because HTTP header injection is possible or HTTP Response Splitting see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting .. No sure if this is fixed in the modern PHP versions.

Comment: I was under the assumption that if i posted my form and used enctype that the header would not be compromised then a prepared statement for handling information going in/out of the DB

Comment: Damn, looks like I'm going to have to soldier on with it haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer for your MySQLi usage is you didn't bind the parameters, which you can do using `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` (Future readers, this last statement is now irrelevant due to edits). Overall your sql statements post-editing seem unclear, you would typically either be updating a password (in which case you need a `WHERE` clause so you don't update *everyone's* password), or you should be inserting a new user with a password.

This is a more-or-less tangential answer, but I would like to throw my hat into the ring for the use of `PDO` (instead of mysqli). MySQLi works with only one form of database flavor, MySQL. Additionally it allows for a much less object-oriented solution to db interactions. Here's an example of how you could accomplish this through PDO:

```
//specifies the driver, ip/database etc. Swap out for your ip and database used
$driverStr = 'mysql:host=<ip>;dbname=<database>;charset=utf8';
//you can set some default behaviors here for your use, I put some examples
//I left a link below so you can see the different options
$options = [
    //spew exceptions on errors, helpful to you if you have php errors enabled
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

//substite what you need for username/password here as well, $options can be omitted
$conn = new PDO($driverStr, '<username>', '<password>', $options);
```

[Link to the aforementioned attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

Now that we've made our connection:

```
//I used a "named parameter", e.g. :password, instead of an anonymous parameter
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Photographers SET password = :password WHERE Username = :username");

//with our prepared statement, there's a few ways of executing it

//1) Using #bind*
//there's also #bindValue for not binding a variable reference
//for params, PARAM_STR is default and can be safely omitted
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();

//2) Using execute directly
$stmt->execute(['password' => $password, 'username' => $username]);
```

Then, were the statement a query and not just a database update/insert, we can simply retrieve the results of the statement. By using #bindParam you can also just update the variable's values and re-execute the statement if you like, which may be useful to you for some other statements.

```
//see #fetch and #fetchAll's documentation for the returned data formatting
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //return it as a php object
$results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)[0]; //unsafely retrieve the first value as a number
```

Over the years I've found this to be much cleaner and more managable than any of the `mysqli_*` or even the deprecated `mysql_*` methods.

Comment: Thank you for your input, defiantly food for thought there and have given me much to think about in how i approach future projects. I dont claim to be a Web Dev but appreciate the work that goes into such tasks. On another note i did infact solve my current issue I understand my code wasnt formatted the best but my code editor doesn't play well with the system stackoverflow seems to have indenting and what not and wanted to provide my code as quick as possible. it was just simple UPDATE and then specifying my fields. A silly problem but i did mention the fact that it may be a silly solution.